# Getting text inside of a search input and give a variable the text value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, there is an input tag that has the id bar, and it's a search input.

`<input id="bar" type="search">`

and I tried to get the value of that input with jQuery.

`var query = document.getElementById("bar");`

And it opens a new tab that searches whatever you typed  into the search bar into google. But it doesn't get the text, it just says 'undefined'. And no, I typed stuff.

[Repl](https://sea-search--seamore.repl.co/)

Comment: That's not jQuery. You need the value, not the element. `var value = document.getElementById("bar").value;`

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, you have the element, you just need to extract the value from it, using the `.value` property:

```js
    <input id="bar" type="search">

    var query = document.getElementById("bar").value;
                                              ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the input of it like this:

```
var query = document.getElementById('bar').value;
```

Also I recommend using `let` instead of `var`

Answer (score 0):

Just add ".value" like this:
`let query = document.getElementById("bar").value;`

Also, try to use template literals for concatenating strings with variables for more readability.

Here if you want to read more about [Template literals.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
So that your concatenation would like:

`` window.open(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${query}`,"Result") ``